# Normalize raster in R

Tags: r, raster-calculator

I'm a noob in R.
I want to normalize all imported rasters (0-1) through R, I use the scale function but the range of the results is not between 0-1. I would like to know if there is any way to normalize a raster layer or a way to normalize the whole raster stack.

```
    precipitation2008_2018_pre <- raster('precipitation.tif')
    precipitation2008_2018_pre
###class      : RasterLayer 
##dimensions : 1859, 1802, 3349918  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
##resolution : 100.0063, 100  (x, y)
##extent     : 342449.5, 522660.8, 3334993, 3520893  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
##crs        : +proj=utm +zone=50 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
##source     : precipitation.tif 
##names      : precipitation 
##values     : 0, 1705.285  (min, max)   
    normal_pre <- scale(precipitation2008_2018_pre)
    precipitation2008_2018<-normal_pre
    precipitation2008_2018
###class      : RasterLayer 
##dimensions : 1859, 1802, 3349918  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
##resolution : 100.0063, 100  (x, y)
##extent     : 342449.5, 522660.8, 3334993, 3520893  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
##crs        : +proj=utm +zone=50 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
##source     : memory
##names      : precipitation 
##values     : -0.9642503, 1.359989  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scale values from a range of `(a,b)` to a range of `(0,1)` you subtract `a` and then divide by `b-a`.

Here's a raster from 3 to 6:

```
> r36 = raster(matrix(c(3,4,5,6),2,2))
> r36
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2, 2, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 3, 6  (min, max)
```

so to normalise (although I'd not say this was "normalising" since that might imply some sort of transform to a "normal" distribution) I'd write a function:

```
raster01 = function(r){

# get the min max values
  minmax_r = range(values(r), na.rm=TRUE) 

# rescale 
 return( (r-minmax_r[1]) / (diff(minmax_r)))
}
```

Then:

```
> rn = raster01(r36)
> rn
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2, 2, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

and now `rn` is a scaled version of `r36` from 0 to 1.

Comment: Thank you very much, The problem is solved when I use your code. But I want to know if this kind of function can also be used directly if I already stack some raster layers.

Comment: There are functions in `raster` that can apply across layers, but its not clear from the Q if you want to normalise each layer to (0,1) or the entire stack. Also, you should look at solutions with the `terra` package instead, since is newer (and better?) than `raster` for raster processing these days.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a general and memory-safe approach with "terra", the (much better) replacement of "raster" that works with one or multiple layers.

Example data

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))  * c(1,10,100)
```

Solution

```
nx <- minmax(s)    
rn <- (s - nx[1,]) / (nx[2,] - nx[1,])

rn
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#names       : red, green, blue 
#min values  :   0,     0,    0 
#max values  :   1,     1,    1
```

Comment: Hijmans normalized the data: zi=xi−min(x)max(x)−min(x).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if there is a R base function for this, but you can make your own custom function easily and apply this on the raster values like this:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.34

r <- rast(ncols = 100, nrows = 100, 
          xmin = 0, xmax = 25, ymin = 0, ymax = 25, 
          crs = "epsg:4326") 

set.seed(101)

# Initialize raster data
r1 <- init(r, fun = rnorm(n = ncell(r), mean = 100, sd = 20)) 
r2 <- init(r, fun = rnorm(n = ncell(r), mean = 100, sd = 20)) 

# Stack raster
r_stack <- c(r1, r2)

r_stack
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 100, 100, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 25, 0, 25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> sources     : memory  
#>               memory  
#> names       :    lyr.1,    lyr.1 
#> min values  : 31.00101, 22.46423 
#> max values  : 171.1525, 189.4160

# Function to be applied on the raster values; return: SpatRaster object
rescale01 <- function(x) {
  
  val <- values(x)
  
  values(x) <- (val - min(val, na.rm = TRUE)) / (max(val, na.rm = TRUE) - min(val, na.rm = TRUE))
  
  x
}

# Rescale values of SpatRaster object with nlyr = 1
r1_01 <- rescale01(r1)

# Rescale values of SpatRaster object with nlyr > 1
r_stack_01 <- lapply(r_stack, rescale01) |> rast()

r_stack_01
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 100, 100, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 25, 0, 25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> sources     : memory  
#>               memory  
#> names       : lyr.1, lyr.1 
#> min values  :     0,     0 
#> max values  :     1,     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Update:** `rescale01` can now be applied on a raster object with multiple layers, corresponding to a raster stack. Maybe this can be adopted to `raster` using the approach provided by @Spacedman.

Comment: That's using `terra` but the question is using `raster`, and reading the data with the `raster` function so its only one layer. Also this code is scaling both layers by the same factors so that only one layer is (0,1). It also won't work if there's NA values in the raster.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the latter - will try to fix this later. Thanks. Since @bangmin li did not say explicitly he wants a `raster` only solution, just a function for rescaling, he can decide for himself if `terra` suits his needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I need to solve next, rescale for single raster layer and rescale for Rasterstack. Sorry for not writing clearly on the code in the question.

Comment: @Spacedman: The issues mentioned should be fixed now. Thanks again for the pointer.  `na.rm = TRUE` should be self-explanatory and a combination of `lapply` and `rast` makes the function now applicable on a raster stack from my point of view. But yes, I'm stubborn and still sticking to `terra` here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `scale` function you may try the following code. It will normalize the values using minimum and maximum values of the raster.

library(raster)

precipitation2008_2018_pre <- raster(vals = 1:64800)

min_val <- min(precipitation2008_2018_pre[], na.rm = T)

max_val <- max(precipitation2008_2018_pre[], na.rm = T)

normalize_ras <- (precipitation2008_2018_pre - min_val)/(max_val - min_val)

Answer (score 0):

The [first answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/437601/107424) did not work for me:

```
nx <- minmax(accstack)   ##accstack is a 1.6Gb tiff file imported as SpatRaster
```

Warning message: [minmax] min and max values not available. See 'setMinMax' or 'global'

```
nx   ##find out why
```

accstack

min      Inf

max     -Inf

Ok, so returning -Inf and Inf, not max and min, I do not know for sure why, I suspect it's the size of the raster. Instead, this did work:

```
maxr <- global(accstack, fun="max")
minr <- global(accstack, fun="min")
accstackn <- (accstack - minr[1,]) / (maxr[1,] - minr[1,])  #worked as expected
```